# Link whatsapp to the website using javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Using Javascript, I want to be able to open a WhatsApp on both IOS and Android.

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
window.open("https://wa.me/15551234567");

window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567");
```

It currently works for Android, however does not work on IOS.

Comment: window.open("https://wa.me/15551234567");
for me this work also in IOS what device you used to test?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the user is use android or ios, so after send the correct link.